# Flutter: Share of state variable to child widget

Tags: flutter, widget, state

I have a screen of my application displaying details of a resource (a main category here). The data is retrieved from a backend API, hence not available on the screen's initial display.

Here is my (simplified - I removed the irrelevant parts) code:

```dart
class MainCategoryDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mainCategoryId;

  MainCategoryDetailScreen({required this.mainCategoryId});

  @override
  State<MainCategoryDetailScreen> createState() =>
      _MainCategoryDetailScreenState();
}

class _MainCategoryDetailScreenState extends State<MainCategoryDetailScreen> {
  final _mainCategoryProvider = Get.find<MainCategoryProvider>();
  late MainCategoryModel _mainCategory;
  bool isMainCategoryLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMainCategory();
  }

  void _getMainCategory() async {
    _mainCategoryProvider
        .getMainCategory(widget.mainCategoryId)
        .then((mainCategory) {
      setState(() {
        _mainCategory = mainCategory;
        isMainCategoryLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: title(
        context,
        titleText: 'Page title',
      ),
      body: Padding(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // ...,
              MainCategoryDetailInfoCard(
                  mainCategory: _mainCategory!,
                  isLoading: isMainCategoryLoading),
              // ...,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `MainCategoryDetailInfoCard` widget:

```dart
class MainCategoryDetailInfoCard extends StatefulWidget {
  MainCategoryModel? mainCategory;
  bool isLoading;

  MainCategoryDetailInfoCard(
      {required this.mainCategory, required this.isLoading});

  @override
  State<MainCategoryDetailInfoCard> createState() =>
      _MainCategoryDetailInfoCardState();
}

class _MainCategoryDetailInfoCardState
    extends State<MainCategoryDetailInfoCard> {
  MainCategoryModel? mainCategory;
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mainCategory = widget.mainCategory;
    isLoading = widget.isLoading;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Info card is built");
    return Column(children: [
      subTitle(
        titleText: 'Infos',
      ),
      labelledInfo(
        label: 'Name',
        value: isLoading ? '' : mainCategory!.name,
        isLoading: isLoading,
      ),
      // ... Rest of infos,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Before that, the code of the `MainCategoryDetailInfoCard` widget was in the parent widget (as a function) and it worked just fine. The screen was able to refresh based on the state values being updated (when the category is retrieved from the backend API).

But after creating the `MainCategoryDetailInfoCard` widget for code clarity purposes, I got the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building MainCategoryDetailScreen(dirty, state: _MainCategoryDetailScreenState#025bc):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
MainCategoryDetailScreen.  main_category_list_screen.dart:87
```

> The line 87 is when the screen is called from another screen.

I know that the `mainCategory` variable is `null` and that the child widget has trouble processing it when it's being loaded from the API.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

`_mainCategory` in `_MainCategoryDetailScreenState` doesn't have any value initially and you are assigning it by fetching it in `initState` method and that's fine but during process of fetching it is obvious that `build` method will do it's process and show widget and in `build` method , you are using `_mainCategory` with `!` null check operator and that's why it is throwing error . So you just need to remove this `!` operator and need to check whether it has value or not before you use it and if it doesn't have any value then don't use it or use some default value if you really need it

For ex :-

You can replace this code

```
MainCategoryDetailInfoCard(
                  mainCategory: _mainCategory!,
                  isLoading: isMainCategoryLoading),
```

To This

```
MainCategoryDetailInfoCard(
                  mainCategory: _mainCategory,
                  isLoading: isMainCategoryLoading),
```

I am able to show only this much code as we don't have full code but yes if you get idea then you can do it by yourself

Comment: Thanx for getting back at me Jayesh.
Your solution was not a fix for me.
But while playing with the code, I found the issue.

In the `_MainCategoryDetailInfoCardState.build` function, I use state variables which are initialized on screen first display (`_MainCategoryDetailInfoCardState.initState`). Then, when the category is loaded, the MainCategoryDetailInfoCard variables are updated but not the state's ones.

By getting rid of the state's variables and using directly the widget's variables, it works

Comment: Basically, I went back to a StatelessWidget